# Simplify the following method

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

The following method needs simplification so that lines become relatively small.

```
    def rep(m):
        if m.group(0) == " " or m.group(0) == "_":
            return "[ _]"
        elif m.group(0) == "(" or m.group(0) == ")" or m.group(0) == "*" or m.group(0) == "+" or m.group(0) == "=" or m.group(0) == "?" or m.group(0) == "!" or m.group(0) == "^" or m.group(0) == "-":
            return "\\" + m.group(0)

    return re.sub(r"[ _()*+=?!^-]", rep, s)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your function? Also, is that last return supposed to be inside the function?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: yes, it is inside

Comment: "lines become relatively small" shouldn't become a metric you hold yourself to

Comment: Use `in` for existence check like, `m.group(0) in ["(", ")", "*",...]`

Comment: Maybe you could add a description of what the code is supposed to do? And some example combinations of input and output?

Comment: @hansolo or even `m.group(0) in '()*+=?!^-'`

Comment: @bereal Yep, that should work too. And it should be that instead of the `list`, since it checks for only a single `char`acter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope It may Help !!

```
def rep(m):
    if m.group(0) in (" ","_"):
        return "[ _]"
    elif m.group(0) in ("(",")","*","+","=","?","!","^","-"):
        return "\\" + m.group(0)

return re.sub(r"[ _()*+=?!^-]", rep, s)
```